# Prevent MMA from saving results in Out[]

Tags: memory

MMA automatically saves every result which then can be called via `Out[]` where the argument needs to be given as `%n` and `%n` corresponds to the output one wants to refer to. Now this automatic saving works even if you end your lines with a `;` or `//Quiet`. However, if one wants to re-evaluate a cell many times with a memory hungry output, one runs into memory issues. How can one change this automatic behaviour of MMA and save results only in variables which one defines but NOT the output of a cell automatically in `Out[]`.

Comment: try `$HistoryLength = 0`?

Comment: See [common pitfalls / $HistoryLength](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978/4999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `$HistoryLength` to `0` [(docs)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$</span>HistoryLength.html) :

```
$HistoryLength = 0
```